# Why does mysqld use much more memory than expected?

Tags: linux, mysql-8.0

Running MySQL 8.0.24, I have been recently seeing frequent instances where the RHEL7 OS will kill the `mysqld` process as the system memory gets all used up. The server has 65 GB of memory, and I think I have MySQL configured to use only approximately 36 GB.

| Parameter | Setting |
| --- | --- |
| key_buffer_size | 8 MB |
| + tmp_table_size | 8192 MB |
| + innodb_buffer_pool_size | 27648 MB |
| + innodb_additional_mem_pool_size | 1 MB |
| + innodb_log_buffer_size | 16 MB |
| + |  |
| max_connections | 150 |
| × |  |
| sort_buffer_size | 0.25 MB |
| + read_buffer_size | 0.125 MB |
| + read_rnd_buffer_size | 0.25 MB |
| + join_buffer_size | 0.25 MB |
| + thread_stack | 0.27343750 MB |
| + binlog_cache_size | 0.03125000 MB |

Totals: 36041.95 MB

However, if I monitor processes in the OS, using `top`, I see that `mysqld` is using more and more memory over time, and by the time Linux kills it, `mysqld` is using over 90% of memory, almost 60 GB.

I have seen the frequency of this increase of late, and it usually occurs while I am running a PHP script that does about 3000 queries in quick succession (selects), one every 5 to 15 seconds. Sounds like a lot, but should not be a problem. PHP is NOT running on the same server.

Any ideas on why `mysqld` continues to consume memory, given its configured variables listed above?

Comment: Sorry for the hard-to-read table. It rendered correctly in the editor when I was writing the question.